# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I am a novice in learning selenium with python.

Problem Statement:-

Getting the following error while trying to identify an object in the chrome browser.

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'**

I understand that the class variable is declared as a string and the assigned web element is getting not referred when I invoke class variable 'driver' from seleniumConfig.py class but not sure how to rectify this fundamental problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note: The browser is getting launched and the URL is getting applied properly but the problem starts when I want to click an object on the page.

Robot Framework:-

```
*** Settings ***

Resource        /foo/boo/selenium_Keywords.robot

SampletestRun
    [Documentation]  To validate
    [Tags]  samplerun
    Launching Browser
    Login
```

**selenium_Keywords.robot**

```
   *** Settings ***
    Library       /foo/boo/SeleniumConfig.py
    Library       /foo/boo/Pratice.py

    *** Keywords ***

    Launching Browser
        browser
        url 

   Login
        click_button
```

**SeleniumConfig.Py**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumConfig():
  driver=""

def __init__(self):
  self.driverPath="foo\boo\chrome.exe"

def browser():
  SeleniumConfig.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.driverPath)

def url():
 SeleniumConfig.driver.get("www.google.com")

def get_driver()
 return SeleniumConfig.driver
```

**Selenium.py**

```
from foo.boo.SeleniumConfig import SeleniumConfig
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class Selenium():
  driver=SeleniumConfig()

def __init__(self):
  self.driver = Selenium.driver.get_driver()

def click_object(webelement):
  element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
                    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, webelement)))
  ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()
```

**Practice.py**

```
from foo.boo.Selenium import Selenium

class Practice():
  sm=Selenium()

  def click_button(self):
        Practice.sm.click_object("webElement")
```

**Traceback Results:-**

```
SampletestRun :: To validate                                          | FAIL |
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element'
```

Comment: In click_object(), does element actually store an element?

Comment: @Sri It is to click the given web element only. Actual issue is the call 'Selenium.driver.get_driver()' product empty string. Therefore script producing such error.

Comment: You dont need to give path of chrome.exe instead of that please download latest chrome driver which support to your browser version and provide binary path https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @DipakBachhav Thanks!. Any assistance on actual issue?

Comment: Any assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Seems, Selenium on Python got confused after they marked as deprecated some find_elements with css locator.

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, webelement)))
```

changed to another method `visibility_of` and it works now: instead of tuple of By and locator it takes an element.

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of(browser.find_element(By.ID, webelement))
)
```